# waiting for data to load into the database then show it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where when a link is clicked an image is created and its data is saved to the DB. When that link is clicked it will load a modal as well. I want the modal to come up then load the image when it's ready. The image is created with a combination of cloudinary and the url2png plugin. The image is created after_commit after some other record specific data is saved:

```
after_commit :async_set_image, on: :create

  private


  def async_set_image
    url2png = Cloudinary::Uploader.explicit("#{root_url}/snapshot/#{id}/url2png/viewport=2200x680|say_cheese=true", type: 'url2png')
    update_attributes(image: url2png)
  end
  handle_asynchronously :async_set_image
```

This is my post

```
snapshotModal: ->
    $.post "/api/snapshot", (data) ->
      $("#temp-my-designs-container").show() ->
        # DO SOME PROMISE STUFF HERE?
      return
```

So Some data gets saved the DB and when the async_set_image method finally returns data it gets loaded into the DB. How can I get that data after the data is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronicity**

You might want to check out the difference between [asynchronicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) and synchronicity - being *asynchronous* means that it's outside the scope of your typical application flow:

> In computer science, asynchronous I/O, or non-blocking I/O is a form
>   of input/output processing that permits other processing to continue
>   before the transmission has finished.

This means, in a simple level, that whenever you send an "asynchronous" request, it will run in the background - independent of any other processes. This is the way it needs to be handled -- if you want to rely on its processing, you'll be working with a *synchronous* request

---

**Implementation**

What you want to look at it is how you're calling the request, and consequently, how that will return the data you want

Your Rails flow will go like this:

`request > router > controller > model > controller > DOM`

This means that your request will not depend on your model as much as it depends on your controller. As Rails is an [MVC (Model View Controller)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework, you'll need to rely as much on the controller as you will the model to receive a request.

To this end you'll be best sending an ajax request to a specific `controller#action`, which you can then work with in the DOM

--

```
#app/assets/javascripts/your_javascript.js.coffee
$.ajax
 url: "/api/snapshot"
 data: data
 success: (data) ->
   # this is where your returned data will come
```

This [ajax (Asynchronous Javascript And XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request to your controller, which I presume will then pass the data to your model? After that, you'll be better getting rid of the delayed job asynchronicity, allowing your front-end Ajax to handle the timely response:

```
#app/controllers/snapshots_controller.rb
Class SnapshotsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      #perform stuff here
   end
end
```